# grouping and averaging the rows based on specific columns in python- rephrase

Tags: python

I have a big `tab separated` file like this:

```
chr1    9507728 9517729 0   chr1    9507728 9517729 5S_rRNA
chr1    9537731 9544392 0   chr1    9537731 9547732 5S_rRNA
chr1    9497727 9507728 0   chr1    9497727 9507728 5S_rRNA
chr1    9517729 9527730 0   chr1    9517729 9527730 5S_rRNA
chr8    1118560 1118591 1   chr8    1112435 1122474 AK128400
chr8    1118591 1121351 0   chr8    1112435 1122474 AK128400
chr8    1121351 1121382 1   chr8    1112435 1122474 AK128400
chr8    1132513 1142552 0   chr8    1132513 1142552 AK128400
chr19   53436277    53446295    0   chr19   53436277    53446295    AK128361
chr19   53456313    53465410    0   chr19   53456313    53466331    AK128361
chr19   53465410    53465441    1   chr19   53456313    53466331    AK128361
chr19   53466331    53476349    0   chr19   53466331    53476349    AK128361
```

according to the last column there are 3 groups and every group has 4 rows. based of the value of 4th column I want to get the average of 1st row of every group, 2nd row of every group, 3rd row of every group and 4th row of every group. so, in the expected output I would have 4 rows (since there are 4 rows per group) and 2 columns. the 1st column is ID and in this example would have 1, 2, 3 and 4. the 2nd column would be the average values that I mentioned how should be calculated.

`expected output`:

```
1   0.33
2   0
3   0.66
4   0
```

I am trying to do that in python 2.7 using the following command:

```
file = open('myfile.txt', 'r')
average = []
for i in file:
    ave = i[3]/3
    average.append(ave)
```

this return only one number which is wrong. do you know how to fix it to get the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it:

```
with open("myfile.txt") as inFile:
    lines = [" ".join(line.split()) for line in inFile]
    s=0
    for i in range(4):
        for j in range(0,9,4):
            s += int(lines[i + j].split()[3])
        avg = s / 3
        print("%d   %.2f" % (i+1, avg))
        s=0
```

Output:

```
1   0.33
2   0.00
3   0.67
4   0.00
```

or you can use list comprehension:

```
with open("myfile.txt") as inFile:
    lines = [" ".join(line.split()) for line in inFile]
    s = [sum([int(lines[i + j].split()[3]) for j in range(0,9,4)]) for i in range(4)]
    avg = [elem / 3 for elem in s]
    for i, value in enumerate(avg):
        print("%d   %.2f" % (i+1, value))
```

Keep in mind that the above code snippets where tested in the exact data format you provided in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you read your data into a `pandas.DataFrame` this is quite easy.

```
import pandas as pd
# name the columns, makes the rest of the code easier to understand
bed_columns = ['chrA','startA','endA','the_value','chrB','startB','endB','group_name']

# read in the file
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.txt',sep=None,header=None,names=bed_columns)

# incrementing count within each group:
df['position_in_group'] = df.groupby(['group_name']).cumcount()

# average value for each count
desired_output = df.groupby(['position_in_group'])['the_value'].mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution where number of line and records per last line are not fixed.

```
final_dict = {}
count_dict = {}
with open("input_file.txt",'r') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        data = line.rstrip('\n').split()
        code = data[7]
        count_dict[code] = count_dict.get(code,0) +1
        final_dict[count_dict[code]] = final_dict.get(count_dict[code],{})
        final_dict[count_dict[code]]['sum'] = final_dict[count_dict[code]].get('sum',0) + int(data[3])
        final_dict[count_dict[code]]['count'] = final_dict[count_dict[code]].get('count',0) + 1

for key,value in final_dict.items():
    avg = value['sum']/value['count']
    print("{} {:f}".format(key,avg))
```

Output :

```
1 0.333333
2 0.000000
3 0.666667
4 0.000000
```